# Any 'not anymore used' german words like "jawohl" and "Fräulein"?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to know any, shall I say, "out-of-use" german words that may or may not carry connotations, like 'jawohl' or 'Fräulein'. And of course words that would sound somehow weird nowadays. I am doing this simply for fun and knowledge. 
So, more clearly said, write here any outdated german words. :)

Comment: See https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/does-jawohl-carry-nazi-connotations for Jawohl - it is just a normal word. See also https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/986/which-words-or-phrases-should-non-native-speakers-avoid-to-prevent-unintentional

Comment: Welcome Dydydy. The SE policy is, to not thank beforehand in questions, because there is an elaborated system to generate reputation from your thanks instead. Meanwhile, we don't greet with names. Your signature is automatically placed below each question, answer and comment.

Comment: German Language is a question & answer site where we are very good in answering a question on a single issue. Please understand that generating multiple big lists of words would not be a good fit for this site, as we would be unable to select a good answer. Such lists would easily be generated from dictionary entries: e.g. https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/veraltend or https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/veraltet

Comment: Take a look at that: https://amp.welt.de/kultur/article184451502/Lorette-Rassenschande-nonen-Wie-Woerter-aus-dem-Duden-fallen.html

Answer (score 6):

**Jawohl.** simply means *Got it.* It's not outdated. You may hear

> Jawoll!

quite often if one acknowlegdes something which went well. For example, commenting a good move in a football game.

**Fräulein** is not used any more to address unmarried women. You may still hear it when parents address their daughter.

> Ach, das Fräulein will wieder mal verreisen. – Ja, Papa!

Comment: While I agree with what you wrote, this doesn’t answer the question at all. (Not that I’m in favor of answering this question in the first place.)

Comment: Have a look at https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexikon_der_bedrohten_W%C3%B6rter and https://www.achgut.com/artikel/unvollstaendige_liste_ausgestorbener_bzw._kaum_noch_benutzter_woerter_begri

Answer (score 2):

There is such a lot of these words. I'll provide you the first two that came into my mind: `wohlfeil` and `feilbieten`. Enjoy :-)

Few days ago for some reason another quite outdated word that you might like came into my mind: `allenthalben`. It's one of my favorites but I almost never use it because many people don't even understand it anymore.

Comment: These are really outdated. Most people had to look them up.

Comment: So maybe you'll like `Oheim` as well.

Comment: Yes, I like it. You know, examples like that. Maybe you can tell me more :) Like, veryy outdated terms

Comment: Among role players these are still in everyday - well, everygame - use

Answer (score 0):

The couple of outdated words that come to mind are *mädel* and *schweinhund*. I have heard of the former popularity of these words, but haven't personally experienced it. 
Nevertheless, I especially like *schweinhund* and would like to see it make a comeback.

Comment: It's *Schweinehund*. It never was *Schweinhund*. Both *Mädel* and *Schweinehund* are still in use.

Comment: In addition to what Janka said, the [innere Schweinehund](https://www.thelocal.de/20181019/german-word-of-the-day-innere-schweinehund) is probably immortal.

Comment: I wish I would have learned this years ago. I was taught that schweinhund was an insult toward someone, but this makes much more sense.Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Schweinehund is indeed an insult. Schweinhund is a misspelling usually in English speaking movies.