# How to refer to a woman based on her age?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

For example, you wouldn’t use *girl* for a 40 years old woman or *kid* for a 20 years old woman (unless you’re far older).

*Fräulein* for single woman between what ages?
What is the age range for *Mädchen*?

Comment: "Fräulein"  is an old-fashioned minefield. Avoid it or risk offending a woman. As a non-native speaker you shouldn't use "Mädchen"  for anyone older than 18. And you shouldn't use Frau for anyone younger than about 16. Between 16 and 18 you should look for context, i.e., is it more a "children topic"  or more a "grown-up topic".

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/966/why-is-fr%C3%A4ulein-considered-offensive-as-opposed-to-frau

Comment: @chirlu "weibliche Person", "weibliches Wesen", oder wenn es wirklich ein Wort sein soll: "Weibchen"

Comment: @Roland: Please do not use comments for answering the question.

Comment: @Em1: "weibliche Person" sounds very technical. "weibliches Wesen" sounds almost comical and "Weibchen" is used for female animals. So don't use any of these in a "normal" (other than technical comical or zoological) context.

Answer (score 32):

*Fräulein* is not typically used any more. In fact, a lot of women can become quite upset if addressed this way. (Quite some time ago it described an unmarried woman, completely independent of her age).

You would use *Mädchen* for children and every time you wish to point to the fact that they are minors. After that, it would either be *junge Frau* or simply *Frau*.

Please note that the transition from *Mädchen* to *Frau* is a very soft one. In an official context, you would not use *Mädchen* for a woman of 18 years or more. In a more colloquial setup, that can be extended, and in a private context, there is no age limit for *Mädchen*.

The former german chancellor, Helmut Kohl, used to call Angela Merkel *Mein Mädchen*, which was supposed to express that he was fond of her, and on quite friendly terms. Angela Merkel at the time was well in her thirties.
It can also transport the age difference.
Again, note that someone has to be quite close for this word usage.

Comment: The decision whether to use _Mädchen_ or _Frau_ (and _Junge_ or _Mann_) is similar, but not equivalent, to the decision whether to use _du_ or _Sie_.

Comment: Is my notion that _Dame_ is predominantly used for elderly women false?  I recognize that in polite conversation (say, a waiter addressing any female adult) it is used for younger people, too.

Comment: @dezso Dame is not necessarily used for elder women, but rather a sign of respect. I use it very often if I am referring to a female person I do not know, when talking to somebody I do not know. Just as I would use "Lady".

Comment: I would say that "when to use Mädchen or Frau" follows the exact same rules of "when to use girl and woman" in English

Answer (score 24):

### das Mädchen (neuter)

»Das Mädchen« is the historical diminutive of »Die Maid«. »Die Maid« has the same etymologic root as the english word »the maiden« and has a very similar meaning. A *Maid* was a young woman, often meant as sexually mature, but still being a virgin. A small (younger) *Maid* was a *Maid-chen*, which was always written as *Mädchen*.

So, a *Mädchen* is a female child. But when time passed by, the word *Maid* was used less frequently, and *Mädchen* began to be used in the same meaning as *Maid* before. In the 1970’s *Mädchen* was the usual word for women younger than 25 or 30 in a non-official context (among friends, but not in the job or in a shop or office).

But things changed again. Young women wanted to be respected in the same way as men of the same age. So, they didn’t want to be called »Mädchen« when they were physically mature women.

Nowadays it is safe to call a girl younger than 13 a »Mädchen«. If a woman is older then 18 or 20, then only her boyfriend/partner/husband might call her »Mädchen« (and only if she likes to be called so). So, as rule of thumb: When you can guess, that she is older than 14 or 15, avoid to call her »Mädchen«. She will like to be called »junge Frau« or just »Frau«.

### das Fräulein (neuter)

»Das Fräulein« is also a diminutive. It literally means »small woman« or »little woman«. When the word »Maid« began to disappear, it was replaced from the younger end of its meaning-spectrum by »Mädchen«, as described above, but also from its older end by »Fräulein«. When the *Maid* has gone completely, »Mädchen« and »Fräulein« overlapped.

»Fräulein« was extensively used between 1850 and 1950, and had a more serious and mature touch than »Mädchen«. When ever a young tough woman was working and earning money (which was unusual in those days), she was called »Fräulein«. (The »Fräulein vom Amt« was the young lady who manually connected lines for phone calls, and a young female teacher was »das Fräulein Lehrerin«)

This is, why »Fräulein« became a synonym for the waitresses in a café or restaurant. This synonym is so branded in the German speaking society, that many people even in 2015 don’t know how to call a female waiter other than »Fräulein«, which is a problem, because »Fräulein« nowadays is considered political incorrect.

When ever »Fräulein« was used for children, then in one of two meanings, both somehow ironic:

- To a 5 year old girl in its new dress, to make her a compliment:

  > Oh, du bist heute aber schon ein richtig großes Fräulein in dem schönen Kleid!
- To a 5 year old girl who was caught eating hidden cookies, in a strict tone:

  > Na, mein Fräulein, habe ich dir das erlaubt?

But since »Fräulein« is a diminutive whose meaning can be interpreted as »a woman, but not for 100 %«, young women began to dislike it even more than »Mädchen«. And nowadays the usage of »Fräulein« is considered political incorrect. You better never use this word.

### das Weib (neuter)

»Das Weib« never was used for girls or young women, always for mature women only. In days, long ago, German had this two pairs of words of adult people of different gender:

1. der Mann — das Weib
2. der Herr — die Frau

The first pair was used when the topic was the being and behavior as human creature (eating and drinking, sleeping, and of course sexuality). And when ever the differences was pointed out (*der starke Mann* — the strong man; *das verführerische Weib* — the seductive woman) this pair was used. And for that reason we still have this pair of adjectives:

> männlich — weiblich (male — female)

The second pair (Herr–Frau) was used in a more sophisticated and cultural context. We still use this pair in salutations and addresses:

> **Frau** Martha Eisenstädter
>   Landstraße 12
>   2080 Irgendwo
>
> **Herr** Josef Steiner
>   Gartenlaubenweg 6a
>   8712 Woanders

### die Dame (female)

But in 16<sup>th</sup> century in aristocratic societies the french word *dame* (french »dame« = mistress, woman, wife) was imported into German vocabulary, and over the centuries it changed the pairs:

1. der Mann — die Frau
2. der Herr — die Dame

This happened hand in hand with the devaluation of »Weib«.

### die Frau (female)

If you want to refer to a women older than 15 or 18, then »Frau« is almost always the best choice. It is not a grammatical neuter diminutive like »Mädchen« or »Fräulein«, and it has not this somehow eccentric and uppish aura that sometimes is around the word »Dame«.

Comment: There's a word that hasn't been mentioned yet on this thread and I wonder why your thorough answer doesn't contain it. Possibly because it's not used in Austria. The word I'm talking about is "Mädel", synonym to "Mädchen", but to my mind quite frequently used in colloquial when referring to a young woman.

Comment: It’s a common misconception or misrepresentation that (young) women in the “_Fräulein_ era” did not work (just marry and bear children). They might have been exempt from “career jobs” and excused in the noble class, but there were plenty of women working in farms, factories, households etc.

Comment: _Dame_ is a funny and sad case. Standing alone (or besides _Herr_), it is associated with higher prestige than _Frau_ (or even _Weib_), but due to that it is often used in compounds and contexts that have low prestige (and would otherwise use diminutive _Fräulein_ or _Mädchen_), e.g. _Bardame, Animierdame, Anstandsdame_. That’s why it has been criticized by feminists, but much less than _Fräulein_ and _Mädchen_ (especially when used for adults). It is also often used with animals instead of _Weibchen_, e.g. Elefantendame_, and in sports, e.g. _Damenmannschaft_.

Comment: @Em1: Is »Mädel« a word of standard German? I thought it was dialect, but Duden contains this word and it says it is bavarian/austrian. But here in Vienna the dialect word »Mäderl« is used more frequently, and it is used for children

Comment: @Crissov: In Germany, from 1880 to 1919, and from 1923 to 1951 (in Baden-Würtenberg up to 1965), there was a law that made it impossible for married women to work as teacher (or other kind of officer). If you was a female teacher during this period and wanted to marry, you had to quit your job. Same for Switzerland between 1912 and 1962 https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehrerinnenzölibat

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Yes, like I said, women (and other social groups) were excluded from **some** jobs, sometimes by law and sometimes by tradition (“common sense”), but they still worked, as did many children. That’s even without counting unpaid labor at home or in family-run shops. This is hardly about German language anymore, though.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast It's colloquial, but certainly not restricted to dialects from Southern Germany.

Comment: @Em1 In non-dialectal scenarios, _Mädel_ is mostly used by and for young women to refer to their female friends, as in _Mädelsabend_ and _meine Mädels und ich gehen feiern_. The closest male counterpart would be _Kumpel_. Notice the same ending _-el_ (with totally different etymology).

Comment: @Crissov And I didn't even think about this. This additional usage makes the word even more common than I thought in the first place.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast There is a difference between "Mäderl" and "Mädel". The former is a local version of "Mädchen" in all its connotations, the other is much closer to the English "girl", in that it can be used to refer to children as well as women in a colloquial setting. "Mädelabend" as the equivalent of a "girls' night out" is pretty much ageless.

Comment: The -el in Mädel is a diminutive just like the -chen in Mädchen. It is used regionally. Compare *Hänsel und Gretel*.

Comment: @CarstenS It is, but the thing with diminutives is that they are sometimes conventionalized, i.e. they gain a very specific meaning beyond smallness and therefore have to be listed in a dictionary as a separate lemma from the base lexeme. _Märchen_, for instance, is not (just) a small _Mär_ and _Brötchen_ is not any kind of small _Brot_. Likewise, two diminutives based upon the same word but using different endings (i.e. derivative morphemes) can differ in meaning and usage, e.g. _Mädel_ vs. _Mädchen_, _Fräulein_ vs. _Frauchen_ and _Männchen_ vs. _Männlein_.

Comment: Interestingly, some derivations are almost immune to this, that means the meaning of the derivate is transparent. Most notably this applies to _+in_ which always limits/changes the extension of the base word to females. It’s therefore unnecessary to put words derived in such way into a dictionary, unless you want to inflate the lemma count or, in this particular case, to please some feminists.

Comment: @Crissov, sure. I imagine that *Mädel* (or *Madel*?) is used in the same way as *Mädchen* where *-el* is generally used as a diminutive ending, and has a different usage elsewhere. I have nothing to support that hypothesis, though.

Answer (score 12):

In short:

- **Mädchen** will usually emphasize the young age (< 18) of the person. It may also be used expressing fondness. It is also used in the context of fashion models. (cf. *girl*)
- **Fräulein** is deprecated. It was used for unmarried women, which means you are inferring a maritial status, which might be offending. It was also used for waitresses, stewardesses, receptionists etc, implying they were not married. It sounds almost despective nowadays. (cf. *Miss*)
- **Dame** is a formal way to refer to somebody. It is very respectful and in my opinion the word of choice in public space when referring to and/or talking to somebody you don’t know. “Meine Dame” can be used to address somebody but it sounds a little old-fashioned. Addressing a group of people, e.g. in a speech or letter, it is commonly used in the phrase "Meine Damen und Herren" resp. "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren" (cf. *lady, Madame*)
- **Frau** is a neutral way of referring to an adult or close-to-adult woman (> 16, maybe > 14, depending on the context). It is also used to address sombody formally appending the last name. (cf. *woman, Ms*)

Comment: "Dame" is still frequently used when formally addressing a large audience, as in "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren".

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking for referral to third persons, (‘the woman I met this morning’) the general terms you want to be aware of are:

- Mädchen (and its dialectal forms like *Madl, Mädel, etc.*)
- Frau
- Dame

*Mädchen* works as long as the person can be considered a child or (young) teen, i.e. [you would address them using *du*](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/77/15318). (The overlap is not perfect but close enough.)<sup>†</sup>

*Dame* when used outside of certain special environments,<sup>‡</sup> would be used exclusively when referring to elderly women with grey (or white) hair and at least a walking stick.<sup>♦</sup>

*Frau* would be used for everything else.<sup>♠</sup>

Do not use *Fräulein* unless you are prepared for the shitstorm that will follow. It is no longer considered adequate.

---

†: Note that the dialectal forms, especially *Madl* (Bavarian) can be used for young adults, too. Referring to grown women as *Mädchen* can be understood as anything between belittling and affection (cf the various references on this page to Helmut Kohl’s *Mädchen* Angela Merkel). I use *Madl* for all my female friends even if they are well in their twenties.

‡: In service environments, e.g. higher class restaurants, *Dame* and *Herr* may exclusively be used instead of *Frau* and *Mann* signifying the higher class as highlighted e.g. in [Hubert’s answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/26646/15318).

♦: You *can* put your foot in it by using the word too liberally. I was once told off for using *Dame* referring to a woman who clearly felt younger than she looked (although she did fulfil the criteria of walking stick and grey hair).

♠: Note that *Frau* is *never* wrong for people older than *Mädchen.* specifically, it is *always* okay to refer to very old women as *Frau.* See also the note above.

Comment: Pro tip: Teach your toddlers to address every women they don’t know by name as _Dame_ and they will get away with saying even nastier things than usual, because it’s just s.oO cute. (_Herr_ doesn’t work quite as well.)

Comment: I do not agree that the usage of *any* of these words has to do with the physical condition of the person.