# Alternativen zu „Junge“ und „Mädchen“

Tags: single-word-request, synonym

Gibt es in irgendeinem aktuellem deutschen Dialekt Bezeichnungen für männliche oder weibliche Kinder und Jugendliche, die einerseits nicht offensichtlich mit *Junge, Knabe, Bube* bzw. *[Mädchen/Maid/Magd](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26639/how-to-refer-to-a-woman-based-on-her-age/26646), Dirne/Deern* verwandt sind und andererseits keine negativen Konnotationen aufweisen (wie bspw. *Schickse, Ische, Fräulein*)?

Comment: Sind _Bursche_, _Steppke_ und _Pimpf_ für Dich innerhalb der Randbedingungen?

Comment: @Matthias Ja bis jein. _Bursche_ (und _Bengel_) habe ich tatsächlich vergessen bzw. übersehen. Die anderen beiden hätte ich eher als Synonyme von _Kind_ als von _Junge_ gesehen. Allerdings interessieren mich die weiblichen Alternativen etwas mehr als die männlichen.

Comment: _Bengel_ hat für mich einen leicht negativen Klang, _Steppke_ wäre für mich tatsächlich immer ein Junge. Weiblich ist mir bislang nur _Schnecke/Schnegge_ eingefallen, wobei die Konnotation vermutlich stark kontextabhängig ist.

Comment: Gör/Göre für ein Mädchen kann, muss aber nicht negativ konotiert sein

Comment: @Matthias: Schnecke ist mir nur sexualisiert bekannt. Racker ist wohl auch nicht neutral. Quest kenne ich aus dem moselfränkischen, für Kinder, unspezifisch, finde es aber nicht belegt, auch nicht als Kwest oder mit d am Ende.

Comment: _Kerl_ für ‘Junge’ gibt’s noch in einigen kleinen Gebieten. Frühere Dialektwörter für ‘Mädchen’ wie _Wicht_, _Luit_, _Fehl_ sind wohl weitgehend ausgestorben.

Comment: Aus dem Wienerischen (und auch in anderen ostöstereichischen Dialekten), geschlechtsunspezifisch: [Gschrapp](http://www.echtwien.at/home/literatur/lexikon/G/1124)

Comment: Der Schwabe sagt "a Mensch" oder "Menschle" und meint damit ein Mädchen. Der Begriff hat eine ähnliche Nebenbedeutung wie "Göre"

Comment: Und natürlich spricht man ganz allgemein von *Nachwuchs*

Comment: Anderer schwäbischer Begriff (nur im Familienkontext für Sohn, Tochter, kleiner Bruder/Schwester gebraucht): *dein Jonger/dei Jonge* - Das ist *nicht* die Dialektform von "Junge"

Comment: @tofro finde ich interessant, in (Ost-)Österreich gibt es den Ausdruck sg. Mensch, pl. Menscha (gesprochen Mendsch und Mendscha) für Mädchen. Bei uns ohne Wertung.

Comment: Evtl. auch nur vergessen, da nicht dialekt-spezifisch: *der Kleine, die Kleine*. Und wie @chirlu schon anmerkte, ist *der Kerle* im Schwäbischen eine Alternative für *den Bub* oder *das Büble*.

Comment: "das Mensch" (für *Mädchen*, im Gegensatz zu "der Mensch") ist im Schwäbischen übrigens erstaunlicherweise *Neutrum*. Ich vergaß.

Comment: @tofro in Ostösterreich auch. Soll ja von Mädchen kommen ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Österreich, zumindest im Osten des Landes, werden weibliche Kinder, Jugendliche und junge Frauen im Dialekt gerne als

> Singular: das Mendsch
>   Plural: die Mendscher

bezeichnet. Das d wird aber besonders im Singular oftmals weggelassen, so dass man oft auch

> das Mensch

hört. Im Plural ist das *d* jedoch nicht zu überhören, und mutiert manchmal sogar zu einem *t*.

Damit existiert in Österreich neben »das Mädchen«, »das Fräulein« und »das Weib« noch eine weiter sächliche Bezeichnung für weibliche Personen.

»Das Mendsch« wird aber häufig ironisch abwertend verwendet, verfehlt also die Forderung, keine negative Konnotation aufzuweisen. In diesem Punkt liegt »das Mensch« in etwa gleichauf mit »das Fräulein«. Das soll heißen: Es gibt Menschen, vor allem ältere Jahrgänge, die sowohl »das Mendsch« also auch »das Fräulein« ganz ohne abwertende Absicht verwenden. Damit befinden sich diese Leute aber in der Minderzahl.

Zu ergänzen ist, dass auch das Wort »der Mensch« in derselben Region oft mit einem d ausgesprochen wird. Jedoch wird der Plural anders gebildet:

> der Men(d)sch
>   die Men(d)schn

Im Plural »die Mendschn« tritt das d (falls es überhaupt gesprochen wird) auch nicht so hervor wie in »die Mendscher«.

Wegen des anderen grammatischen Geschlechts und wegen der anderen Art den Plural zu bilden (und natürlich wegen der anderen Bedeutung) halte ich »das Mensch« und »der Mensch« für zwei verschiedene Wörter, also für Homophone die nicht miteinander verwandt sind.

Leider kann ich zur Etymologie von »das Mensch« gar nichts sagen.

Comment: Im Niederdeutschen gab es die Eigenart, (Ehe-)Frauen als „de _Nachname_ +(i)sche“ zu bezeichnen, z.B. _de Müllersche_. Könnte _Men(d)sch_ einen ähnlichen Ursprung haben? Neutrum für Mädchen und Frauen ist bzw. war relativ weit verbreitet, _dat Lisbeth_ etc.

Comment: An diesen Ursprung glaube ich nicht, weil das Men(d)sch in Österreich sehr verbreitet war (jetzt weniger), aber an die Namen von Frauen und Mädchen nie eine besondere Endsilbe angefügt wurde. Ausnahmen waren nur Namen, die auf -er enden, diese wurde manchmal - in Anlehnung an Berufsbezeichnungen - scherzhaft zu -erin: Leitner -> Leitnerin, Derler -> Derlerin. Wie gesagt: nur zum Scherz, und das sehr selten. Niemals aber z.B. Fink -> Finkin, Schölnast -> Schölnastin. Ich kann mich aber nicht erinnern, dass -(i)sche angehängt worden wäre.

Comment: Ich glaube das Neutrum für Mädchen war eher im Bereich der Alemannischen Dialekte verbreitet, also Schweiz und Schwabenland. Man kann es z.B. in den Heidi-Romanen von Johanna Spyri nachlesen (Z.B. Titel des zweiten Bandes: »Heidi kann brauchen, was **es** gelernt hat« http://www.amazon.de/Heidi-kann-brauchen-was-gelernt/dp/3791535471) Darin wird für **das** Heidi immer das Pronomen *es* verwendet, seltsamerweise aber für **die** Klara (Heidis Freundin) aber immer *sie*.

Comment: Wie in meinem Kommentar von oben schon erwähnt, gibt es *das Mensch* als Ausdruck für ein Mädchen oder eine Frau auch im Schwäbischen. Je nach Situation kann der Ausdruck (noch) neutral, öfters aber Richtung der Bedeutung "Göre" tendieren, bei einer erwachsenen Frau ist der Ausdruck Hinweis auf einen schwierigen und möglicherweise offensiven Charakter....

Comment: Bei _Heidi_ ist Neutrum gewissermaßen konsequent, weil es sich wie bei vielen Namen auf /i/ um einen Diminutiv (von Adelheid o.ä.) handelt. Es müsste dann natürlich auch _das Hansi_ heißen. Das Suffix _-in_ wird erst seit relativ kurzer Zeit systematisch und nur für die Tätigkeitsbezeichnung von Frauen verwendet, früher wurde es auch und eher an den Beruf oder Namen des Ehemannes (oder ggf. Vaters) angehängt – nicht scherzhaft.