Wovon ist "Mädchen" ein Diminutiv?
What is the etymology for the word das Mädchen especially in light of similar words listed below.



Grund-Substantiv
Diminutiv




Schwein
Schweinchen


Hahn
Hähnchen


Haus
Häuschen


????
Mädchen




Related https://german.stackexchange.com/a/26646/4782

Btw. it should be Häuschen, not Hauschen :-)

Ursprünglich die Maid, aber dieses Word ist veraltet und im heutigen Deutsch ungebräuchlich.

www.duden.de sagt "Herkunft - für älter: Mägdchen, eigentlich Verkleinerungsform von Magd".
