# Wie verwendet man Titel in der Anrede einer E-Mail?

Tags: salutation, letter

Ich möchte in einem Programm automatisch E-Mails an bekannte Kontakte generieren.
Wie sollte die Anrede dieser E-Mail aussehen?

Die Titel, die ein Kontakt in dem Programm haben kann, sind:

- Doktor
- Professor
- Professor Doktor

Außerdem kann jeder Kontakt eine der folgenden Anreden haben:

- Frau
- Fräulein
- Herr

Nun bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob die Mail z.B. wie folgt beginnen sollte:

> Sehr geehrter Herr Dr. Mustermann,

oder vielleicht

> Sehr geehrter Dr. Mustermann,

hier würde ich intuitiv die erste Version verwenden, aber wie verhält es sich für eine Professorin?

> Sehr geehrte Frau Professor Musterfrau,

oder

> Sehr geehrte Professorin Musterfrau

---

1. Wann kombiniere ich die geschlechterspezifische Anrede (Frau/Fräulein/Herr) mit dem Titel?
2. Wann schreibe ich den Titel aus, wann nicht?
3. Wird "Professor" für Frauen zu "Professorin"?

Comment: eine Professorin ist eine Lehrerin. eine Frau mir Professortitel ist Frau Professor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Auf [Studis Online](https://www.studis-online.de/Studieren/Richtig_schreiben/anrede_und_gruss.php) ist die Anrede eines Professors im Brief so erklärt:

1) Nur der höchste Titel wird verwendet, es gibt also keinen Professor Doktor sondern nur einen Herr Professor/Frau Professorin Muster

2) Der Doktor-Titel wird abgekürzt: Sehr geehrter Herr/Frau Dr. Muster

Fräulein ist veraltet und könnte anstößig wirken.

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde schreiben

> Sehr geehrte Frau Professor Musterfrau
>
> Sehr geehrter Herr Professor Mustermann
>
> Sehr geehrte Frau Dr. Musterfrau
>
> Sehr geehrter Herr Dr. Mustermann

Siehe auch https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Professorinnen-und-Professoren-anschreiben-oder-anreden und https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Anrede-von-Doktorinnen-und-Doktoren

Die Anrede *Fräulein* ist veraltet, wird nicht mehr verwendet, und gilt als herabsetzend. Im Übrigen wurde auch früher, als *Fräulein* noch für unverheiratete Frauen verwendet wurde, auch eine unverheiratete Frau nicht mehr mit *Fräulein* angesprochen, wenn sie promoviert war, auch wenn es das *Fräulein Doktor* ganz zu Beginn, bei den ersten promovierten Frauen, wohl noch gegeben hat.

Comment: Leider soll das Programm sowohl deutsche als auch englische Mails erzeugen können. Im Englischen wird aber quasi immer das Äquivalent von Fräulein, "Miss", verwendet und nicht das Äquivalent von Frau, "Mrs". Soll ich dann einfach auf die Anrede "Fräulein" verzichten und immer nur "Frau/Miss" verwenden?

Comment: Unter dem Link in der Antwort von infinitezero steht, dass man "Sehr geehrte Frau Professor**in** Rede" schreiben soll - das hier nur der Vollständigkeit halber. Da es sich um ein multilinguales Programm handelt, werde ich das aber vermutlich der Einfachheit halber nicht tun.

Comment: @TheBlackIPs Ja, aber ich würde dem Duden hier eher trauen als studis-online.de

Comment: Leuchtet ein, aber da der Duden die Schreibweise Professor*in* auch erwähnt, ist die andere Antwort zumindest nicht falsch.

Comment: @TheBlackIPs: "Da es sich um ein multilinguales Programm handelt, werde ich das aber vermutlich der Einfachheit halber nicht tun." - wenn das verwendete Lokalisierungsframework so was nicht hergibt, ist das ja eigentlich ein starkes Argument, ein anderes Framework zu verwenden ...

Comment: @O.R.Mapper So intensiv habe ich mich noch nicht mit dem Framework beschäftigt... Ich weiß, dass es Pluralisierung von Übersetzungen unterstützt, aber Unterscheidung von Geschlechtern habe ich noch nicht gefunden.

Comment: Ich mag es falsch machen, aber ich schreibe immer "Lieber Herr Prof. Mustermüller" und "Liebe Frau Prof. Schlaumeyer".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich denke, dass das so auch nicht unüblich ist. In meinen Augen gibt es eine Chance, dass die längere, ausgeschriebene Version einen höheren Grad der Wertschätzung transportiert.

Comment: @TheBlackIPs, “Ms” ist nicht “Miss”.

Comment: @TheBlackIPs Im Deutschen würde ich einfach alle Adressatinnen mit _Frau_ anschreiben, wie das im Englischen ist, weiß ich nich so genau.

Comment: ["Fräulein" wäre geradezu eine Beleidigung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/966/why-is-fr%c3%a4ulein-considered-offensive-as-opposed-to-frau), ähnlich schlimm, als würde man *"Liebes Herrchen Prof. Weber"* schreiben. Ich habe auch gelernt, dass man den *Professor* in der Anrede nicht abkürzen darf und ich halte mich daran.

Comment: Mein amerikanischer Professor hatte erwähnt, dass auch Ms ein Relikt ist und man lieber nur noch Mrs verwendet.

Comment: @infinitezero    Und was sagt er zum traditionellen "*Missus*" ?

Comment: Das weiß ich nicht. In dem Gespräch vor ein paar Tagen ging es tatsächlich nur um die Anreden in Formularen, also Mrs., Ms. und Mr.
Dabei erwähnte er, dass Ms jetzt eben ganz universell durch Mrs abgelöst wurde.

Comment: @infinitezero Meinte er damit denn Ms. oder Miss? Da gibt es ja laut Carsten S. einen Unterschied. Hier steht auch, dass Ms. verwendet werden soll, wenn der Beziehungsstatus unbekannt ist: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/address-lady-business-letter-34388.html